# How to monitor Windows system API calls an application makes?

Tags: python, c++, windows, winapi

I am trying to build an application that takes, as input, the windows system API calls that a program makes. For this, I need a way to log the API calls that any program makes in real time.

I've tried using NtTrace but it seemed to not give consistent results across different systems. I tried using the GUI based API monitors but they are rather heavy and slow for my application.

Is there any other way one can achieve this? Perhaps maybe a Python or a C++ library that allows one to do this?

Comment: "I need a way to log the API calls that any program makes in real time" - That's a project in itself! See if you can work around that with detecting some output/artifect say "find the window opened", "file written to disk" etc. Still if you choose to do it, this might help - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44326/MinHook-The-Minimalistic-x-x-API-Hooking-Libra   and   https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2082/API-hooking-revealed

Comment: Ah damn! NtTrace was really useful but it was slowing down the application which is something I would prefer not to. I will look into the link you posted. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

[Detours](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/detours/?from=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fprojects%2Fdetours%2F) is a software package for monitoring and instrumenting API calls on Windows.

`Detours` is a software package for monitoring and instrumenting API calls on Windows. 
`Detours` has been used by many ISVs and is also used by product teams at Microsoft. `Detours` is now available under a standard open source license (MIT). This simplifies licensing for programmers using Detours and allows the community to support `Detours` using open source tools and processes.

`Detours` is compatible with the Windows NT family of operating systems: Windows NT, Windows XP, Windows Server 2003, Windows 7, Windows 8, and Windows 10. It cannot be used by Window Store apps because `Detours` requires APIs not available to those applications. This repo contains the source code for version 4.0.1 of `Detours`.

It is distributed in source code form: https://github.com/microsoft/Detours